# Universal remote control with bluetooth emitter

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, remote-control

I am creating a universal remote control to replace multiple devices I have at home. The IR part was quite easy to implement.

I realised then that the Chromecast with Google TV remote uses Bluetooth, and **only Bluetooth**, instead of IR.

I have another remote (Foxtel, Australia) that is also Bluetooth, but it accepts IR, so I can just use IR.

I tried to connect the remote to my mobile but, although it shows on the mobile as a possible device to connect, it doesn't complete the connection process.

Is it possible at all to clone the remote into an Arduino and make the Arduino connect to Chromecast to send the commands?

Kind Regards,
Eduardo

Comment: The first question to find the answer to would be, what communication profile is advertised by the remote. Bluetooth can carry many different profiles (for example HID, Serial, audio, ...). Without knowing that you cannot reproduce it. On your mobile you would need a fitting app, that controls the bluetooth interface. Don't know, if such an app exists.

Comment: Now you are on... Why just not build from scratch your new Remote? Just a sugestion ofc

Comment: @k.Cyborg, that is what I am doing. The problem with Chromecast is that it doesn't accept anything else but Bluetooth. For all the IR remotes I have a prototype working. I need to understand and clone the Bluetooth one. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh, that's a nice project then. I suggest you use the usual HC-05 (or the HC-06) modules if you are a newbie into the electronics, do not buy clone modules from China because they are harder to use and understand. And... Read how the Bluethooth protocol works, so you can easilly work with it. Greetings mate, and good luck